# Forging SSL/TLS packets with Scapy (python)

Tags: library, python

I am trying to forge some SSL/TLS packets but I haven't found any libraries on Scapy so far. Are there any public SSL/TLS libs for Scapy or equivalents ?

If it doesn't exist with Scapy, is there any Scapy equivalent program that would help to perform the same objectives?

It must be able to create record, handshake and error packets, in that I mean all kind of SSL/TLS content.

OpenSource and free software would be great, or free software if they are  actually none. Is it possible to link Scapy with OpenSSL  for instance ?

Comment: Do you care about license? how about pricing?

Comment: Opensource would be great, if there are existant tools. Otherwise, free softwares.

Answer (score 4):

There is Scapy TLS that implements some parts of the TLS protocol such as:

- TLSClientHello
- TLSServerHello
- TLSCertificate
- TLSServerNameIndication
- TLSChangeCipherSpec
- TLSHeartBeat

Code example:

```
import scapy
from scapy.layers.ssl_tls import *

import socket

target = ('target.local',443)

# create tcp socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(target)

p = TLSRecord(version="TLS_1_1")/TLSHeartBeat(length=2**14-1,data='bleed...')

s.sendall(p)
resp = s.recv(1024)
print "resp: %s"%repr(resp)
s.close()
```

The extension can be found here:

https://github.com/tintinweb/scapy-ssl_tls

Answer (score 0):

You can try [tls_prober](https://github.com/WestpointLtd/tls_prober) (or rather [pytls](https://github.com/WestpointLtd/pytls/)). It claims to be able to create various TLS messages, although I found that the code in the [presentation](http://www.westpoint.ltd.uk/papers/low-level-tls-hacking.pdf) does not work as advertised.  However, code like this seems to work:

```
def make_heartbeat():
    heartbeat = HeartbeatMessage.create(HeartbeatMessage.HeartbeatRequest,
                                        'X', 0x4000)

    record = TLSRecord.create(content_type=TLSRecord.Heartbeat,
                              version=TLSRecord.TLS1_0,
                              message=heartbeat.bytes)

    #hexdump(record.bytes)
    return record.bytes
```

Answer (score 0):

There is [tlsfuzzer](https://github.com/tomato42/tlsfuzzer) which not only has generators for various messages [[1](https://github.com/tomato42/tlsfuzzer/blob/1f76a59cf8b8ee860761531692d671f350715c48/tlsfuzzer/messages.py#L280), [2](https://github.com/tomato42/tlsfuzzer/blob/1f76a59cf8b8ee860761531692d671f350715c48/tlsfuzzer/messages.py#L280)], it can also verify if the server replies are as expected [[3](https://github.com/tomato42/tlsfuzzer/blob/1f76a59cf8b8ee860761531692d671f350715c48/tlsfuzzer/messages.py#L280), [4](https://github.com/tomato42/tlsfuzzer/blob/1f76a59cf8b8ee860761531692d671f350715c48/scripts/test-cve-2016-2107.py#L29)] (messages sent, their contents, presence of alerts, etc.), it has support for negotiating (and re-negotiating) [[5](https://github.com/tomato42/tlsfuzzer/blob/1f76a59cf8b8ee860761531692d671f350715c48/scripts/test-openssl-3712.py#L27)] full TLS session as well as resuming it [[6](https://github.com/tomato42/tlsfuzzer/blob/1f76a59cf8b8ee860761531692d671f350715c48/scripts/test-sessionID-resumption.py#L26)].

From major TLS features, only ECDSA and session tickets are not supported, everything else like protocol itself from SSLv3 to TLSv1.2, ECDHE, RSA, DHE, AES-GCM, ChaCha20, client certificates, and many others works as expected. At the same time, it doesn't depend on external cryptographic libraries so all those features are supported on distributions as old as RHEL/CentOS 5 (provided that Python 2.6 from EPEL is installed) and as new as current Archlinux with Python 3.5.

To generate completely arbitrary messages, you can use `RawMessageGenerator`, like this:

```
node = Connection('example.com', 443)  # TCP level connection
node.add_child(RawMessageGenerator(ContentType.application_data,
                                   bytearray(b'Raw data in message')))
runner = Runner(node)
runner.run()
```

*Full disclosure: I'm the primary developer of tlsfuzzer.*